# Libreoffice 6: no text shown in Juno version

Tags: libreoffice

I installed Libreoffice from the app store; did not look well (buttons, bars, etc., looked like very old GNome). I changed to one of the icon themes, and all text was vanished. What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `libreoffice-gtk3` and `libreoffice-style-elementary`.
Then go to preferences and select Elementary as default icons.
Also use Elementary icons as your default system icons.

Comment: You're welcome!